# Can i use icloud data without coredata?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud

I'm new in icloud.I'm searching about how to do this in the rigth way.
But my questions is
Do I have to implement core data to store documents on icluod?
how can I do it?
Does anyone have a good tutorial about icloud?

I have this code

```
-(NSString *)archivePathWithName:(NSString*) name {
NSArray *documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];

return [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

}
```

then i save it like that

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:items toFile:[self archivePathWithName:name]];
```

is that being saved at iCloud?

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't have to use Core Data.

- You can use the key value store of an iCloud **OR**
- You can just save your files in your app's iCloud document folder and they'll be synchronized automatically

Core Data iCloud support only gives you incremental updating of a database across devices - which is very nice if you need it... Almost no delays :)